# How can I evaluate: $\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos \theta}}d\theta$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I want to evaluate:

$$\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos \theta}}d\theta$$

I get stuck if I try a $u$ substitution and I have tried changing the expression using trigonometric identities but still no luck.

How would I go about evaluating this ?

Comment: Use $$1-\cos \theta=2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the fact that $1-\cos\theta=2\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$ to transform the integral in question into

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_a^b \left\vert \:\csc\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \right\vert \, d\theta$$

Does that answer your question?